# Customize Maya's script editor font even if it's docked

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, maya, autodesk

I was playing around with the script editor in MAYA so it always just has a bigger font size.

I found this solution on stack overflow:

[Customize Maya's script editor font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71722293/customize-mayas-script-editor-font/71872223#71872223?newreg=1197640577064785a20340bdb0696351)

But it doesn't work when the script editor is docked. It looks like it cant find the qt widget when its parented under the main maya window? This is my first time playing around with qt stuff so im still a little confused as to how to find that window/panel/qt widget if it's parented under  something different